# Restrict curation task to *single* item

Tags: dspace

Is it possible to restrict a `curation task` to only execute when it is invoked for a single item and abort when it is invoked for a community, collection or the entire DSpace?

I know that it is possible to restrict a `curation task` to process only item**s** as opposed to communities and collections, but that's not what I am looking for.

*Background:*

I have a `curation task` that sends an email about an item.
It is intended to be invoked on a single item.
If someone would accidentally invoke it on a collection or the entire DSpace, it would send thousands of emails, which would be, obviously, a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to be found in the manual:

> Since tasks operate on DSOs that can either be simple (Items) or
>   containers (Collections, and Communities), there is a fundamental
>   problem or ambiguity in how a task is invoked: if the DSO is a
>   collection, should the CS invoke the task on each member of the
>   collection, or does the task "know" how to do that itself? The
>   decision is made by looking for the @Distributive annotation: if
>   present, CS assumes that the task will manage the details, otherwise
>   CS will walk the collection, and invoke the task on each member.

So to make the task non-distributive, you set the `@Distributive` annotation, to tell the Curation System that you handle distribution yourself and then do not implement distribution in your task.

What the `@Distributive` annotation means is, *"handles distribution on its own"* instead of *"let's the curation system handle distribution"*. So the name of the annotation is a bit misleading.

This works when you implement the `org.dspace.curate.CurationTask` interface as well as when you extend the `org.dspace.curate.AbstractCurationTask` class.

Answer (score 1):

You should implements the interface org.dspace.curate.CurationTask instead of extending the org.dspace.curate.AbstractCurationTask class.

Indeed, the abstract class is the one responsible to implement the automatic distribution of a curation task across all the object in a DSpace container (Community, Collection). Implementing directly the interface you can decide to immediately return if the curation is run on a community or collection

```
int perform(DSpaceObject dso) throws IOException {
    if (!(dso instanceof Item)) {
        return Curator.CURATE_SKIP;
    }
    //... do your work on the item
    return Curator.CURATE_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This way I can skip a `Community`/`Collection` object, but the community's/collection's `items` are still processed. It seems that this behaviour is implemented in the `Curator` class' `curate` method, the `distribute` method in `AbstractCurationTask` seems not involved in this at all.

Comment: you are right! You can probably use the @Suspendable annotation over the curation task and return CURATE_FAIL instead of CURATE_SKIP if the dso is not an Item (I haven't tested this but it should work by code inspection)

Comment: Yes, it will work if you use `CURATE_FAIL` instead of `CURATE_SKIP`, but only as long as you assume that the curation system does process the container before the single items (which it does at the moment). But I found a better solution, using the `@Distributive` annotation. See my own answer.